# Conditional JSON Deserialization using C#

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I'm writing a `C#` test automation to validate web services that return JSON strings.  I created a DataContract that mapped to what was being returned. Assume this is what was being returned:

```
{"DataModule" : {"required":"false", "location":"toolbar"}}
```

My test automation was working fine, but then I started getting this error:

> "The data contract type 'DataModule' cannot be deserialized because
>   the required data members 'required, location' were not found."

I checked the JSON and the data module was now

```
{"DataModule" : {"width":"400", "height":"320"}}
```

I discovered that the dev implementation is that if the first type of data module is encountered, the client parses that and creates a button on a toolbar.  If the second type of data module is returned, the button appears on the toolbar AND a panel appears in another location with those measurements.

Is there a way to either create optional members in a data contract OR implement conditional deserialization to account for JSON objects that may have multiple implementations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dave-s

I had already tried adding all of the properties, but since I knew I was on the right track, your suggestion keyed me into something else.  The properties were all decorated with

```
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired = false)]
```

But the class itself, was decorated with only `[Serializable]`.  When I changed `[Serializable]` to

```
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute()]
```

it started working.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare the model with all of the likely properties, only the ones found in the JSON string will be populated:

```
public class DataModule
{
    public bool Required { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Width { get; set; }
    public string Height { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @dave-sI tried this, 

    [Serializable]
    public abstract class DataModule
    {
        public bool required;

        public string location;

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired = false)]
        public int Width;

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired = false)]
        public int Height;
    }
 
but I still get:
 The data contract type 'DataModule' cannot be deserialized because the required data members 'Width,Height' were not found.
 
 When the DataModule being returned is only for a button.